# Send JSON Object to Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi I'm new to rails so please bear with me :) I want to send JSON object to rails and save it to database. basically I have a data entered by the user then I have a javascript function thats retrieves the data and convert it into JSON object. What i want is to sent the JSON object maybe through ajax to rails and save it to the database.Can anyone give me any idea how to do it. thnx

```
function save(){
----(some codes)   
notesArray.push({ Index: i, Title: title.val(), Content: content.val()});

// json encode it
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(notesArray);

//want to add code here to send to rails
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, it's very easy to do this using [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post('/some/page/here', {notes: jsonStr});
```

Comment: how do you handle the JSON object in the controllers. I want to decode it and save the data in database?  Thnx

Answer (score 0):

As to "handle the JSON object in the controllers" you can use `parsed_params = CGI.parse(params[:_json])` ,then  you can get what you what througt `parsed_params[key1][key2]`